# std::vector doesnt accept my struct as template

Tags: c++

So I try to make a `std::vector` containing my struct `tabs`

menu.h

```
class CMenu
{
public:
    void CMenu::addtab(std::string label, CCords pos, int index);
private:
    std::vector<tabs> tablist;
};

struct tabs
{
    std::string label;
    SPoint pos;
    int index;
};
```

menu.cpp

```
void CMenu::Do()
{
    this->addtab("sample tab", CCords( 100, 100 ), 0);
}


void CMenu::addtab(std::string label, CCords pos, int index)
{
    tabs tab;
    tab.label = label;
    tab.pos = pos;
    tab.index = index;
    tablist.push_back(tab);
}
```

When i try to compile this i get these errors.

```
1>c:\cpp\testmenu\menu.h(57): error C2065: 'tabs': undeclared identifier
1>c:\cpp\testmenu\menu.h(57): error C2923: 'std::vector': 'tabs' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
1>c:\cpp\testmenu\menu.h(57): error C3203: 'allocator': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Alloc', expected a real type
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Formally speaking, `tabs` needs to be a *complete type* when `std::vector` sees it. So even a *forward declaration* of `tabs` (which would denote an *incomplete type*) is not sufficient.

That means that the `struct` definition has to appear before `CMenu`.

Note that this rule is relaxed a little from C++17 where the type can be incomplete for the declaration and instantiation of the vector subject to some constraints centred around the vector's allocator; the relevant part of the standard:

> [vector.overview]/3 An incomplete type T may be used when
>   instantiating vector if the allocator satisfies the allocator
>   completeness requirements 17.6.3.5.1. T shall be complete before any
>   member of the resulting specialization of vector is referenced.

Comment: IIRC, incomplete types are supported for `std::vector`, `std::list` in C++17

Comment: @Jarod42 that's only for the template instantiation. For `push_back` and many other operations you still need a complete type.

Comment: @Jarod42: For `std::vector` you're certainly correct. I've added.

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't see any forward declarations in user's question (though his example is not mcve either). It could be something as simple as forgetting to `#include` the relevant header. Not sure if they familiar enough to know about forward declarations not to mention incomplete types, allocators and vector template instantiations.

Comment: @DanM.: Neither do I. But, this question is well-asked (which is why I answered it). I've taken the time to explain the difference between complete and incomplete types which becomes particularly relevant from C++17. Remember that answers are not necessarily tailored to the OP.